# How to generate click event of panelgrid through jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 and primefaces 3.0. I have a rowtoggler and rowexpansion. Since I am using primefaces old version so I dont have rowToggle event. And I need to call a method on server side through ajax at the time of row expansion. So I have put div tag around rowtoggler and calling a javascript function. Now I want to initiate ajax call through click event of panelgrid which is inside rowexpansion. If this happen then it would look like 3.4 rowToggle event.

Comment: Why sitting back with an old version instead of upgrading it?

Comment: I have been provided 3.0 and told to use that only for an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put commandLink arround rowtoggler and I make ajax call through commandlink and I can also pass value through it using EL2.2

```
<p:commandLink action="#{myBean.doSomething(foo)}" >
    <p:rowToggler/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery's event binding to execute Javascript when clicking on the row toggler.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="dt" value="[1,2]">
        <p:column>
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:remoteCommand name="remotecommand"
        oncomplete="alert('remote command fired')" />
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("[id='form:dt'] .ui-row-toggler").on("click", function() { remotecommand(); });
</script>
```

Explanation of Javascript:

The `$("[id='form:dt'] .ui-row-toggler")` selects the datatable by id (`form:dt`) and then selects all descendants that have the style class `ui-row-toggler`.

The `.on("click", function() { remotecommand(); })` binds an anonymous function to a click event which fires a Javascript function declared by `p:remoteCommand`.

You can use the `p:remoteCommand` to execute bean methods with it's `action` or `actionListener`. ;-)

Note that this I don't find this to be a long term solution. Upgrading to PrimeFaces 3.4 would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanx siebz0r.
I am little bit confused. Does it work like ajax? And in backing side what kind of event I have to handle?

Comment: The `p:remoteCommand` calls methods in a backing bean like a `p:commandButton` does, no event handling etc. The `p:remoteCommand`  submits using AJAX.

Comment: Thank u very much for ur replies. :) I will definitely try this :D

Comment: Its showing msg like..
<f:ajax> Parent is not composite component or of type ClientBehaviorHolder, type is: org.primefaces.component.remotecommand.RemoteCommand@d1918a

My code is like...
<p:remoteCommand name="remotecommand" oncomplete="alert('remote command fired')">
     <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{tableBean.ajaxCallThis}"></f:ajax>
    </p:remoteCommand>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("[id='form:dt'] .ui-row-toggler").on("click", function() { remotecommand(); });
</script>

Comment: @KushSahu remove the `<f:ajax>` tag, it doesn't belong there. Use `p:remoteCommand action="#{tableBean.ajaxCallThis}"` instead ;-)

Comment: yes its working :) . Thank you :) . This was the first step for me. May be I need your help again in other steps. Hope you will you will help me.

Comment: Hi can I send any object through any way at this ajax call? Object should be from panelgrid. I tried with <f:param name="abc" value="#{xyz}"/> but its not working.

Comment: @KushSahu Please do not ask follow-up questions in the comments. ;-) It is usually better to ask another question.

Comment: actually it is based upon your ans so I asked again here. :)   .I found that we can not send any object from page. We can send only string. I tried to send an number like <f:param name="abc" value="#{xyz.getnumber}"/>. But in backing bean its showing error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd something like

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.onclick}" />
    ...
    the rest of the grid here
    ...
<p:panelGrid>
```

I haven't tested it but it works for other components

Comment: I have tried this. Buts its not the solution. I want to do it exactly like rowToggle event without using 3.4 version of Primefaces.

Comment: If I can call that click event of panelgrid then I think it would be pretty much similar to rowtoggle event.

Answer (score 0):

Except solution of siebz0r I found one more solution.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.abcFunction}"> <p:rowToggler/> </p:commandLink>
```

it also works and simple too     :-)